# Outlook not allowing tables to display inline block

Tags: email, responsive-design, outlook, html-email, responsive

This is email code that works in web browsers, apple mail, ios mail, but when using Outlook, these elements do not display inline-block.  Any idea as to why and how I can fix this?  I want the button and the image to remain side by side instead of stacked.  Thanks!

```
<table style="display:inline-block; margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;" width="150px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#e9703e"><a href="https://litmus.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #e9703e; display: inline-block;">Read More</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>


<table style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:27px;" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td>

     <a  href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" style="margin-right:10px; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://media.com/FB-02.png"></a>  
     <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" style="margin-right:10px; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://media.com/twitter-03.png"></a>

     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook doesn't have very good support for the css box model, so things like `display: inline-block;` and `margin` don't always work as they do on the web.

**Wrapping the two `<tables>` in a parent `<table>` will display each column side by side in every major email client:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;">

      <!-- your first table : BEGIN -->
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#e9703e"><a href="https://litmus.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #e9703e; display: inline-block;">Read More</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- your first table : END -->

    </td>
    <td width="150" style="padding-bottom:27px;">

      <!-- your second table : BEGIN -->
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" style="margin-right:10px; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://media.com/FB-02.png"></a>  
            <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" style="margin-right:10px; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://media.com/twitter-03.png"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- your second table : END -->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```